# ng-repeat parsing every character of json

Tags: angularjs

Still Trying to track down why I cannot display json data from asp.net webmethod won't display in table using ng-repeat - I've gotten to the point where it looks like there is an issue with my json but I don't see the problem
The table with the server json - I added an index column and it seems to add a row per character ??

Here is a screenshot of the data - There is the json data from the server and a manually created angular collection that looks like my json data

Thanks for any insight

[image]

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test1.aspx.cs" Inherits="SampleAngularjs.Test1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  >

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="codeapp">

  <div ng-controller="CodeController" >
    <button ng-click="doClick(item, $event)">Send AJAX Request</button>
    <br />
    Data from server: {{codes}}
    <br />
    Data from Manually built Collection: {{fields}}
    <br />

    <h3>And here is what you get if you just return the promise returned by $http.get():</h3>
    <pre>{{codes | json}}</pre>

     <br />
    <h3>Manually Built Angular Collection Table</h3>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Desc</th>

    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="code in fields">
        <td>{{code.Code}}</td>
        <td>{{code.Desc}}</td>

    </tr>

   </table>

    <br />
    <h3>Server Json Table</h3>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Row</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Desc</th>

    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="code in codes track by $index">
        <td>({{$index + 1}}) </td>
        <td>{{code.Code}}</td>
        <td>{{code.Desc}}</td>

    </tr>

   </table>

  </div>

   <script>
       angular.module("codeapp", [])
           .controller("CodeController", function ($scope, $http) {

               $scope.fields = [{ Code: "aaa", Desc: "aaa, desc" }, { Code: "bbb", Desc: "bbb, desc" }];

               $scope.codes = [];

               $scope.doClick = function (item, event){

                   $http.post('Test1.aspx/GetAllCodes', { data: {} })
                     .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                         $scope.codes = data.d;

                     })
                     .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                         $scope.status = status;
                     });

               }

           })
           .config(function ($httpProvider) {

               $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};

               $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

           });
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How does your .success `data` object look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting a string from the server and ng-repeat over a string gives you each character.  Try parsing it yourself to see if it works, then check out the request and response headers to see why it isn't sending the data back as `application/json`:

```
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.codes = JSON.parse(data.d);
})
```

Comment: Thanks was able to get results from what you suggested. Previously tried angular.toJson(data.d) but your suggestion worked but still have to track down why correct json not returned from webmethod

Comment: `angular.fromJson` is what you want to go from json -> object.  I just realized you are using `data.d`, so your results seem to have a json object with a property `d` that is a string, which just so happens to be json.  That must just be how the server is returning data and there's no way to make it detect strings as JSON and automatically parse them.