# Taking data from a JSon using ng-repeat and displaying it

Tags: html, angularjs

code :-

```
{ "Projects": [
 {
    "ProjectName" : "SmarTest",
    "ProjectDescription" : "abc",
    "ModuleDetails": [
        {
           "Maintitle":"Getting Started with IoT1"
        },{
           "Maintitle":"Getting Started with IoT2 "
        }]
  },
  {

    "ProjectName" : "SmarTest",
    "ProjectDescription" : "abc",
    "ModuleDetails": [
         {
          "Maintitle":"Getting Started with IoT3"
        },{
           "Maintitle":"Getting Started with IoT4"
        }
      ]
   }
]}
```

This is my Sample JSON and now i wanted to get Main Title from the first arrays of each `ModuleDetails` using **ng-repeat** (Getting Started with IoT1 and Getting Started with IoT3) and display it .

i tried

```html
<div ng-repeat="Module in Projects.ModuleDetails">
  <div>{{Module[0].MainTitle}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-repeat parsing every character of json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513758/ng-repeat-parsing-every-character-of-json)

Comment: What output did you see when you compiled your code?

Comment: This question does not currently have enough information for us to help you. Please detail the current behavior of your code.

Answer (score 1):

[Check this plunkr, I think this is what you looking for](https://plnkr.co/edit/51JdW6l8RVF2guZgdqwK?p=preview)

Go with something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="ob in data.Projects">
  <div ng-repeat="a in ob.ModuleDetails">{{a.Maintitle}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: out of that i only want Getting Started with IoT1 and Getting Started with IoT3 to be displayed

Comment: @user9664067 : can you mark it as an answer if you got what u were looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
<div ng-repeat="x in mdata.Projects">
  <p>{{x.ModuleDetails[0].Maintitle}}</p>
</div>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.mdata = {"Projects":[
            {"ProjectName" : "SmarTest","ProjectDescription" : "abc","ModuleDetails":[{"Maintitle":"Getting Started with IoT1"},{"Maintitle":"Getting Started with IoT2"}]},
            {"ProjectName" : "SmarTest","ProjectDescription" : "abc","ModuleDetails":[{"Maintitle":"Getting Started with IoT3"},{"Maintitle":"Getting Started with IoT4"}]}
   ]}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please write explanation.